# Beginning with SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint

Hi I am new to sharepoint, and i wanted to know which website provides few tutorials to learn the Sharepoint from the very basic.

I went through few sites all of them try to "beating around the bush" rather than explaining with a hands on.

Please suggest some websites which have hands on to start with.

Thanks.

Comment: First of all, what are you planning to do with sharepoint? (programming, administration, client-side access, ...)

Comment: I am trying to learn programing.
I have to develop a blog site with lot of UI modification, and we are planning to host it on cloud and hence we are not planning to do programming in c#.

I just wanted to see some hands on i have experience in php, javascript, html. But don't have any knowledge on c# or .net i hope they are needed much for Sharepoint.

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't want to program (customizations in sharepoint are written in C#, ASP.NET), then  you should use an application called "Sharepoint Designer". It is sort of an administration tool of sharepoint and allows you to do a lot of different stuff like editing html of templates and such things.

Comment: Thanks for the response RononDex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest start with SharePoint 2013 SDK

http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=30722